# Trying to import an old Eclipse Android project into Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I have an old Android game from 2013 on my Google Drive. 
I downloaded it, and I want to import it into Android Studio.
It was done in Eclipse, so I imported the Eclipse project into Android Studio.
However, I got the following error:

**ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3.**

I also got a warning about having spaces in my directory name:

### Risky Project Location:

The tools *should* handle project locations in any directory. However,
due to bugs, placing projects in directories containing spaces in the
path, or characters like ", ' and &, have had issues. We're working to
eliminate these bugs, but to save yourself headaches you may want to
move your project to a location where this is not a problem.
C:\Users\all\StudioProjects\Sonic Boom
                                 -

I don't know whether or now that is contributing to the problem.

Anyone know how to get past that "ERROR" message?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to update your build.gradle module app file with dependencies and repositories

Comment: I think adding "google()" as a repository to the build.gradle file solved it.